# CS:GO limited to 8 wins only in offline with bots mode

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

There's no "mp_win_limit" nor "sv_maxrounds" / "max_wins" in the console command.
When playing offline with both it is always limited to 8 wins.

Is there a way or a console command to change this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are commands (cvars) that does this.

Your `sv_maxrounds "x"` is actually `mp_maxrounds "x"` - x being the amount of rounds you'd like.

There's also some other time-related cvars such as:

```
mp_maxrounds // Max amount of rounds before map is going to change
mp_timelimit // Map's timelimit
mp_halftime // Whether you'd like to have a half time or not
mp_roundtime // Amount of minutes that you'd like each round to be
```

.. and so on. For more commands you could visit one of the following sites:

http://www.gamerconfig.eu/commands/counter-strike-global-offensive/
https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=186668
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_CS:S_Cvars (This is for CS:S, but a lot of the commands are the same)

Comment: What's the highest value that `mp_maxrounds` can be set to?

Comment: I set it to 9999 (that's then shown in scoreboard) but the match still ended early.

Comment: @Nakilon setting it to 0 should make it endless.

Comment: Oh nvm, maybe the map was switching because of `mp_timelimit`.